# How to add object in singleton NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, nsmutablearray

I used to store the array data downloaded from the server.
But I can not save them in the singleton array.

It seems without access to the object.

Why ulatitude, ulongitude, uaccuracy, uplacename is nil?...

in .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface LocationData : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *ulatitude;
    NSMutableArray *ulongitude;
    NSMutableArray *uaccuracy;
    NSMutableArray *uplacename;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *ulatitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *ulongitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *uaccuracy;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *uplacename;
+ (LocationData*) sharedStateInstance;
@end
```

in .m file

```
#import "LocationData.h"

@implementation LocationData

@synthesize uaccuracy;
@synthesize ulatitude;
@synthesize ulongitude;

+ (LocationData*) sharedStateInstance {
        static LocationData *sharedStateInstance;

        @synchronized(self) {
            if(!sharedStateInstance) {
                sharedStateInstance = [[LocationData alloc] init];
            }
        }
        return sharedStateInstance;
}
@end
```

use

```
[manager POST:urlStr parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {

                 NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

                 // json response array
                 if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

                     NSArray *responseArray = responseObject;
                     NSDictionary *responseDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

                     LocationData* sharedState = [LocationData sharedStateInstance];

                     for(NSUInteger i=0; i < responseArray.count; i++)
                     {
                         responseDict = [responseArray objectAtIndex:i];

                         double dlat = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
                         double dlng = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];

                          [[sharedState ulatitude] addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",dlat]];
                          [[sharedState ulongitude] addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",dlng]];
                          [[sharedState uaccuracy] addObject:[responseDict objectForKey:@"rad"]];
                          [[sharedState uplacename] addObject:[responseDict objectForKey:@"place_name"]];
}
```

Comment: Why do you have instance variables defined, and why synthesize 3 of the properties (instead of zero)?

Comment: Also, unless you aren't using ARC, you should define the properties as `strong` instead of `retain`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your object properly. Basically your member variables ("ivars") are pointing to nothing ("nil").

This initializer added to your .m file code do the job.

```
-(instancetype)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
                    self.accuracy = [NSMutableArray array];
                    self.latitude = [NSMutableArray array];
                    self.longitude = [NSMutableArray array];
                    self.uplacename = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}
```

As a singleton pattern, I'd prefer the following:

```
+ (LocationData*) sharedStateInstance {
    static LocationData *sharedStateInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedStateInstance = [[LocationData alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedStateInstance;
}
```

Although singletons might not be as bad they are often said to be, I don't thing that this is a good usage for them. Your specific problem has nothing to do with that design choice, though.

Comment: Don't forget this is manual reference counting.  Using `self.array = ` is recommended and you should show how what to do in the `dealloc` method too, regardless of the singleton status of the class (someone may decide to make it not singleton somewhere down the line).

Comment: I was assuming that ARC is the standard today unless told otherwise.

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, retain)` tells otherwise.

Comment: @trojanfoe Good catch, have missed that one. Fixed. :)

Answer (score 7):

You always need to initialize your arrays. You should do somewhere before you try to add something to them:

```
arrayName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

otherwise you'll always get error because they have not been initialized.

In your case you should override your `LocationData` `init` function like this:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.yourArrayName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        // And so on....
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: "Somewhere" being `init`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Write getters for your NSMutableArrays.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface LocationData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *ulatitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *ulongitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *uaccuracy;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *uplacename;
+ (LocationData*) sharedStateInstance;
@end


#import "LocationData.h"

@implementation LocationData

@synthesize uaccuracy = _uaccuracy;
@synthesize ulatitude = _ulatitude;
@synthesize ulongitude = _ulongitude;

+ (LocationData*) sharedStateInstance {
        static LocationData *sharedStateInstance;

        @synchronized(self) {
            if(!sharedStateInstance) {
                sharedStateInstance = [[LocationData alloc] init];
            }
        }
        return sharedStateInstance;
}


-(NSMutableArray*)uaccuracy
{
    if(_uaccuracy == nil)
    {
        _uaccuracy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return uaccuracy;
}

-(NSMutableArray*)ulongitude
{
    if(_ulongitude == nil)
    {
        _ulongitude = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return ulongitude;
}

-(NSMutableArray*)ulatitude
{
    if(_ulatitude == nil)
    {
        _ulatitude = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return ulatitude;
}

-(NSMutableArray*)uplacename
{
    if(_uplacename == nil)
    {
        _uplacename = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return uplacename;
}
@end
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to synthesize properties with their default name, and then also have another bunch of differently named ivars around that won't be used at all.

Comment: Even though it will work. It will not lead you towards any error. Moreover you can remove @synthesis. It will also work. I just mentioned this in synthesis so that he may know the concept of ivars. Otherwise he would be thinking from where this "_" sign is coming. You can see I haven't used ivar for uplacename property.

Comment: Down voting for just getting attention towards your answer isn't appreciated.

Comment: I really hate down voting other answers, but this code has severe problems. Fix them, and I'll change the vote. As it stands, this code is a lying mess.

Comment: Have you tried this code? Writing getters is a lying mess, this is what I am hearing for the first time.

Comment: No. I know that it should work in the given context, yet it is just bad. The variables declared in your interface file are not even used at all - just dead storage that's misleading. And it opens the door to many new bugs in the future, as it's trivial to write code that looks perfectly legit and compiles, yet won't work the way it should.

Comment: Ohhh sorry i didn't check the interface. I just copied it from the problem

Comment: Those properties have been removed.

Answer (score -1):

you don't allocate/init any array...

you can create them in your singleton creation method

```
+ (LocationData*) sharedStateInstance {
        static LocationData *sharedStateInstance;

        @synchronized(self) {
            if(!sharedStateInstance) {
                sharedStateInstance = [[LocationData alloc] init];
                sharedStateInstance.ulatitude = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                // (add others...)
            }
        }
        return sharedStateInstance;
}
```

Comment: No.  The `init` method should allocate and initialize the arrays.

Comment: there's no difference, here or in init...  it's a singleton class, and so it's supposed to be a MUST passing by the + (LocationData*) sharedStateInstance method

Comment: Your answer will certainly solve the OPs issue, however it will do it poorly.  `init` is the place to initialize a class instance, regardless of the number of instances that can exist.

Comment: "Your answer will certainly solve the OPs issue"... so why down-vote my answer? it was clear, in the title question too, that we were talking about a singleton class, and it's not a good idea, in general (but exceptions may exits), have a singleton class AND other instances of this class

Comment: @trojanfoe: ok, sorry for thinking that

Answer (score -1):

**Replace your LocationData.m file with below code , this will work . As you have to alloc and init the array then only you can add object in array**

```
+ (LocationData*) sharedStateInstance {
            static LocationData *sharedStateInstance;
                    @synchronized(self) {
                    if(!sharedStateInstance) {
                        sharedStateInstance = [[LocationData alloc] init];
                        uaccuracy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                        ulatitude = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                        ulongitude = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                        uplacename = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    }
                }

            return sharedStateInstance;
    }
```

Comment: This will always work and in shared instance you can alloc and init the array , this will stay as it is and it won't be always allocated and initialized as it is written in shared instance.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes , as it is written inside @synchronized(self) and also it will allocate for single time , when the shared instance is allocated , and whenever applicaton is restart during that time it will allocated once.

Comment: So you can access the property `uaccuracy` from a class method then?

Comment: Well, how to put it... it won't even compile in the first place because there are four variables that are not declared at all.

Comment: Yes , by using 
 LocationData* sharedState = [LocationData sharedStateInstance];
And then sharedState.uaccuracy , you can access the array